# How to stop firebase from automatically retrieving phone verification code and invalidating it in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have implemented firebase login via phone, with sms code verification.
It works smoothly when I enter a different phone number than the one in my device, when I'm using the same phone number in the device, I get an error that the code has expired.

I understand that there is a callback that is called when the user is automatically authenticated, but I don't know how to get a firebase user inside that

```
static PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationCompleted = (AuthCredential user)async{
    await loginWithPhoneNumber(user);
  };

  static PhoneVerificationFailed verificationFailed = (AuthException authException){
    state = FAILED;
    userVerificationState = new UserVerificationState(state, authCredential);
    _authCredentialFetcher.sink.add(userVerificationState);
  };

  static PhoneCodeSent codeSent =
      (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]) async {
        state = CODE_SENT;
        userVerificationState = new UserVerificationState(state, authCredential);
        _authCredentialFetcher.sink.add(userVerificationState);
    verificationCode = verificationId;
  };

  static PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout codeAutoRetrievalTimeout =
      (String verificationId) {
        state = REQUIRES_VERIFICATION;
        userVerificationState = new UserVerificationState(state, authCredential);
        _authCredentialFetcher.sink.add(userVerificationState);
    verificationCode = verificationId;
  };
```

The error shows when I call the function loginWithPhoneNumber inside PhoneVerificationCompleted.

Code for loginWithPhoneNumber:

```
  static Future<FirebaseUser> loginWithPhoneNumber(AuthCredential authCredential) async {
    FirebaseUser fUser;
    try{

      fUser= await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .signInWithCredential(authCredential);
      _authCredentialFetcher.sink.add(new UserVerificationState(VERIFIED, authCredential));
    }
    catch(e){
      print (e.toString());
    }
    return fUser;
  }
```

Comment: Does it allow you to enter the sms when you enter a different phone number?

Comment: Yes, and it verifies correctly if the phone number is not the same one on device

Comment: have you found a solution for this? I'm facing exactly same issue here

Answer (score 0):

you can set time out to zero
that's mean that will never wait to auto verify
But  verificationCompleted function will triggered when you verify manual with code
so you can left it empty or use it in any logic you want to add

*timeout: const Duration(seconds: 0),*